# Linux Kernel - stoping a running kernel timer from user space

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I am trying to blink an LED in my embedded device while Linux is booting. Basically the LED blink shows that Linux is in the process of booting.
To blinks the LED, I am doing the following things

1. Created a global timer (LED blink timer) in init/main.c 
   static struct timer_list pwr_led_timer;
2. Started the timer as soon as init_timers() function is finished in start_kernel()
   setup_timer and mod_timer functions used.
3. When timer fires, in the timer handler, LED is toggled. And timer restarted.
4. When kernel finishes the whole boot process, I am switching off the LED and deleting the timer. 
    del_timer_sync(&pwr_led_timer);

Question:
I would like to stop the timer and switch of the LED from user space from my application instead of stopping at the kernel (that is point number 4). Is there a standard way to stop the kernel running timer from user space ?

since pwr_led_timer is global struct, can any IOCTL call be used to stop the timer from user space ? My Idea is do some IOCTL and get access to kernel. Since the pwr_led_timer is global, in IOCTL I can call the del_timer_sync() with pwr_led_timer. But not sure which device I should open to IOCTL (?)

Sorry, I am new to kernel/driver programming. I tried to search the net but could not get any clue.

Kindly let me know if anyone has any inputs. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Emerson

Comment: Did you consider changing your `/sbin/init` to make the blinking in user space only?

Comment: to create a device for ioctl is very complicated, I suggest you use sysfs instead

Comment: Hi Zang MingJie, Thanks for the comment. As I said earlier I am new to kernel/module programming. I will google to understand how to create sysfs entry for my need (that is kernel timer I need to stop) and give it a try. If you have any link please share it. Thanks Emerson.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying [netlink](http://1984.lsi.us.es/~pablo/docs/spae.pdf)? It's a powerful method for user-to-kernel (or process-to-process) communication which both simple and lightweight.